# auto load attributes to certain category from frontend in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, frontend, dokan

i'm using wordpress and woocommerce and dokan for multivendor ecommerce site

the marketplace website will have multiple categories, each categories have different attributes.

example:

1. Category: Clothing - attributes: size, color
2. Category: Smartphones - attributes: screen size, processor, RAM
3. Category: Car - attributes: make, model, year

so what i need is when vendor add product from frontend, after selecting certain category certain product attributes will load and vendor then have to enter/select the attributes.

than this also will be used when user browsing for certain categories, then certain product attributes filter will be load also.

does anyone know how to achieve this?